# iOS：[NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:inRequest:] return nil

Tags: ios, request, nsurlprotocol

While playing with NSURLProtocol, I found **[NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:inRequest:]** always return nil in **stopLoading**, but work well for **canInitWithRequest:**

```
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    if ([NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:@"URLProtocolHandledKey" inRequest:request]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
- (void)startLoading
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [self.request mutableCopy];
    [NSURLProtocol setProperty:@YES forKey:@"URLProtocolHandledKey" inRequest:newRequest];
}

- (void)stopLoading
{
    if ([NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:@"URLProtocolHandledKey" inRequest:self.request]) {
        NSLog(@"Logging");
    }
}
```

Anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [self.request mutableCopy];
```

You're creating new object here and setting it's property and you're expecting that property in other instance, that's not the right way.

Make your `self.request` as NSMutableURLRequest` so that you can directly pass it. e.g.

```
[NSURLProtocol setProperty:@YES forKey:@"URLProtocolHandledKey" inRequest:self.request];
```

Comment: It depends which request you're passing and also what you expect from your **canInitWithRequest** ? Are you sure you return correct values depending upon the `URLProtocolHandledKey` key?

Comment: Yes，it return NO in **canInitWithRequest:**, otherwise it will keep calling **startLoading**

Comment: **self.request** is NSURLProtocol's inner property

Comment: @keywind What else your are doing in startLoading: method?